# Disable Item Editing in Document Library via Details Pane

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, quick-edit, editing-menu

I have a document library which I have given Read permissions to certain people. Upon checking, the Edit in Grid View button is missing, but they can still edit on the details pane on the right. Is this a bug? It greatly defeats the purpose of restricting edit permissions, if editing is possible in details pane regardless of permission access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain they can edit using the details pane? For users with Read permission, the controls in the details pane are active (i.e. they don't act like disabled controls) but their values are read-only.

If they can actually edit, then I would suggest double checking their permissions to confirm they only have Read permission.

If you confirm the permissions then it sounds like a bug. I would report the issue to https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues

Comment: It seems like it was just a bug. I tested it again, and it no longer is possible to edit